# Вернуть результат команды Print в ячейке Jupyter (Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Уважаемые, у меня очень простой вопрос. 
Я использую Python 3 и Jupyter. Например, выполняю вот такой код:

```
A=7
print(A)
```

В Jupyter данный код занесен в Cell 'In[1]'. Как мне вернуть значение, которое код напечатал командой 'print(A)'? 
Обратиться к команде 'Out[1]' я не могу, т.к. Cell с командой Print не возвращает Out.

Очень-очень нужен ответ. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Я может быть не понял вопрос, но значение 7 у вас сохранено в переменной `A`. Можете использовать ее в любом другом месте. Попробуйте в новую ячейку ввести `A` и выполнить.

Comment: Андрей, обратиться к переменной A конечно проще. Мне надо научиться обращаться к результатам 'печати' ячейки. А как это сделать я не знаю

Comment: Понял. Есть еще один вариант, написал ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Интерпретатор Python хранит значение последнего выполненного выражения в переменной `_` (нижнее подчеркивание). Можете это использовать:

```
In [1]: 3 + 4                                                                                        
Out[1]: 7

In [2]: _                                                                                            
Out[2]: 7

In [3]: _ + 1                                                                                        
Out[3]: 8

In [4]: _ / 2                                                                                        
Out[4]: 4.0

In [5]: A = 7                                                                                        

In [6]: A                                                                                            
Out[6]: 7

In [7]: _                                                                                            
Out[7]: 7
```

Comment: В этом случае возвращается результат 'A=7\nprint(A)'

Comment: @Евгений попробуйте убрать `print()` и вывести просто `A`, я обновил ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ. Научился автоматически определять номер Out, в который произошла запись, затем из нее возвращаю выведенное значение.